# How do I change the BackColor of the textbox area in an asp.net DropDownList?

Tags: asp.net, css, drop-down-menu

How do I change the BackColor of the textbox area in an asp.net DropDownList from white to another color? The Backcolor property changes only the drop down section.

Comment: In which browser?  `<select>` is notoriously un-style-able for many properties, at least cross-browser (I'm looking at *you* IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the background color of a  tag with the following:

```
select {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000; /* if you want a different border */
}
```

Note: IE's styling differs from Firefox though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via an external stylesheet and target the DropDownList's ID, or you can add the CSS property via code, like so:

```
DropDownList.Attributes.Add("style", "background-color: #FF0000")
```

But as Nick pointed out, you may not get your desired result, because form elements inherit from native operating system controls.

Comment: I think it's only fair that I vote you up - you covered the other direction :)